# std::atof or std::stof (c++11) unable to convert properly ("1.24")

Tags: c++, c++11, string-conversion, atof

I'm a little bit frustrated after I've found this strange atof/stof behavior

```
double bg = std::stof("1,24");
std::cerr<<"comma: "<<bg<<std::endl;
bg = std::stof("1.24");
std::cerr<<"dot: "<<bg<<std::endl;
```

when I change the string format, from comma to dot, this is what happens:

```
comma: 1.24
dot: 1
```

has anyone encountered this problem?
thanks

bart

Comment: You must have the French comma style selected in your Windows options.

Comment: I'm on a Linux distro, actually

Comment: You must have the French comma style selected in your Linux options.

Comment: I've solved using istringstream, but however the problem is not the "french comma style"

That one, the "1.24", was just an example. I've encountered the problem reading data from a file, generated with fstream

@QuentinUK, thanks for the answers. However, how can I disable this option?

Comment: You could call `imbue` on the stream object and set a locale without that problem. You could also use `std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));` on your main function but this has a problem that any other thread of your app could change it.